# How to pass an argument in a function that will be the name of a variable?

Tags: python

I want a class with a method that takes a name and creates an object of a different class assigned to that name. How is this possible?

```
class Graph:
    def __init__:
        self.node_list = []

    def node(name):
        name = Node()
        node_list.append(name)
        do_other_things_with(name)

class Node:
    ...
```

Comment: Do you really need that? You could just do `myNode = Node()`, and then just use `myNode` variable. Why do you want to have a variable name specified dinamically?

Comment: I wanted a certain functionality and aesthetic when calling or creating nodes and edges: If `graph1.node(node1)` exists, this syntax returns that node; if it doesn't, it creates that node with that name. Then the user can easily do: `graph1.edge(node1, node2, 'c')`.

Comment: I'd be happy to post the whole program, if you'd like to see it

Comment: Then I guess the best way is to add a `name` attribute to the `Node` class and make it work from there. I would never advise to mix variable names and user defined names (if you get what I'm saying...).